# Getting nodes of a Abstract Syntax Tree of Acceleo Query Language in java

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, acceleo, ecore

I am want to calculate the number of nodes in a AST od a AQL expression.
My code is as following.

```
public static void aqlParser(String queryString ) {

            IQueryEnvironment queryEnvironment = Query.newEnvironment();

            QueryBuilderEngine builder = new QueryBuilderEngine(queryEnvironment);
            AstResult astResult = builder.build(queryString);

            System.out.println(astResult);
            System.out.println(astResult.getAst());

            System.out.println(astResult);
            //AQLSiriusInterpreter asi= new AQLSiriusInterpreter() ; 

}
```

THe idea is to build an expression from a String query and calculate the number of nodes in the AST .

Comment: and the question is

Comment: Is how can I get the node from the AstResult object.